# Auth::checker returns false even if the user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

First, I logged in and it gives off an error "Undefined $scholar" in my view.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
        $scholar = Scholar::where('user_id','=','Auth::User()->id')->count();
        view()->share('scholar', $scholar);
}
```

second,I tried to `dd(Auth::check());` and it returned false while im logged in.
Why is `Auth::check()` returns false even if the user is logged in?

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    dd(Auth::check());
    $scholar = Scholar::where('user_id','=','Auth::User()->id')->count();
    view()->share('scholar', $scholar);
}
```

Comment: why not just use  if(Auth::user()) ? and then change $scholar to:  $scholar = Scholar::where('user_id','=',Auth::User()->id)->count();

Comment: it still gives an "Undefined variable" error .

Answer (score 0):

Three mistakes:

1. Your where clause is putting auth user id inside a quote, so it's evaluating it as a string hence the query is not finding any row
2. You aren't exactly fetching a Scholar row, instead you are querying the count?
3. You are accessing the authenticated user incorrectly

Try this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $scholar = Scholar::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    view()->share('scholar', $scholar);
}
```

P.S. Instead of `Auth::user()->id` you can also use `Auth::id()` - See more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: I tried using this code in Laravel 5.1 and it works . Same with the code i have shown above. But when i used it in Laravel 5.4 it gives an error .

Comment: Maybe the issue is not with the code, but the database? have you checked if theres a row in your scholars table for the authenticated user id?

Comment: Its possible the `StartSession` middleware has not run yet. If this is true `Auth::check()` will return false. Make sure to place this code inside the `web` middleware group. See [Kernel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.4/app/Http/Kernel.php) for details.